# Can you explain me the following java code?It is of Java Output Formatting topic

Tags: java, output

Java Output Formatting topic.
What does cin does? Is it character in? I have added comments to the lines I need help to understand. Basically the for loop and the printf command. Rest is all okay.Thanks in advance.

```
class Solution{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner cin=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("================================");
    for(;cin.hasNext();){  //what is this doing?
        String s=cin.next();
        int a=cin.nextInt(); 
        System.out.printf("%-15s%03d\n",s,a); //What is this doing exactly?
    }
    System.out.println("================================");
}
```

Comment: so you should know about how both `for` and `printf()` will works.

Comment: That loop would be more idiomatically written as `while (cin.hasNext())`

Comment: read [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) of printf method

Comment: @Satya I know how for loop and printf works. I want to know What does this exactly mean "%-15s%03d\n",s,a. How it works?

Comment: @Sarthak Bhatia If your doubt is cleared. You should accept an answer which helps you most by clicking at the hollow tick beside the respective answer. You get 2 rep points in return.

Answer (score 2):

```
% : Begin format specifier

s : Formats value as a String

- : A flag for left-justified
```

`%3d` means there will be a minimum space of width 3 and by default **right** justified.

`%-3d` adding a minus infront will make the text **left** justified.

`%03d` Fill output with zeroes infront. So instead of `7`, `007` will be printed.

`%05d` Another example for the above. So instead of `7`, `00007` will be printed.

---

According to what was given by you: `("%-15s%03d\n", s, a)`

You can deduce the following:

- There are 2 format specifiers (indicated by two %) - Two types of format specified.
- The ***first*** format `(%-15s)` is meant for ***first*** variable `s`.
- The ***second*** format `(%03d)` is meant for ***second*** variable `a`.
- The first variable `s` will be left justified with 15 characters width (Indicated -15s)
- The second variable `a` will be right justified and filled with zeroes infront. (Indicated by %0)
- The second variable `a` will have a width of 3 characters and it is right justified (Indicated by %3d)

---

**Example**:

Running the following code:

```
System.out.printf("%-8s%05d\n","hello", 50);
```

**Output**:

```
hello   00050
     ^^^
     |||
  3 spaces because hello has width of 8 when we write %8s. 
  5 spaces already taken by "hello".
```

Running the following code:

```
System.out.printf("%8s%05d\n","hello", 50);  //Removing the - sign (Right justified)
```

**Output**:

```
   hello00050
^^^
|||
3 spaces comes to the front because we removed the -. Text becomes right justified.
```

Answer (score 1):

System.out.printf("%-15s%03d\n",s,a);

**%3d\n**

% - Begin formatting expression

3d - formatting expression. Expected a value type int. Print right-aligned  with the length 3.

a – int Parameter of %3d\n

**%-15s**

(minus) – Left aligned

5s - Expected a value type string.

s - string parameter of %-15s

Answer (score 0):

> for(;cin.hasNext();){  //what is this doing?

The above is similar as writing:

```
while(cin.hasNext()){

}
```

`hasNext()` returns true if this scanner has another token in its input

---

> System.out.printf("%-15s%03d\n",s,a); //What is this doing exactly?

`printf()` writes a formatted string to this output stream using the specified format string.

Answer (score 0):

**The java.util.Scanner.hasNext() method Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input:**

**in your case it will always return true because you are using :**

**Scanner cin=new Scanner(System.in);***//passing inputs from console*****

following program might help you understand better:

```
public class ScannerDemo {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 String s = "Hello World! 3+3.0=6";


Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNext());
System.out.println("" + scanner.nextLine());
System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNext());
scanner.close();
   }
}
```

**output:**

true

Hello World! 3+3.0=6

false